# How to check special character for variable when delayedexpansion is set

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to know whether the string is having any special character or not.
I tried the following using environment variable, here its detecting `@` character which is working fine

```
@echo off
set x=Stack@123Overflow
echo %x%
echo %x% | findstr /r "^[^\\/?%%*:|<>\_\.-~!@#$&()+="]*$^" > nul
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

The output is `1`:
[image: output 1]

But, when I enable delayed expansion, I am getting `errorlevel` as `0` which should actually be `1`

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set x=Stack@123Overflow
echo !x!
echo !x! | findstr /r "^[^\\/?%%*:|<>\_\.-~!@#$&()+="]*$^" > nul
echo %errorlevel%
pause
```

Here is the output of second code (output is `0`):
[image: output 0]

I want to achieve this using delayedexpansion enabled only and I want to use it with wmic (`wmic logicaldisk get VolumeName`) command

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET count=0
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%F IN ('wmic logicaldisk get VolumeName') DO (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%B in ("%%F") do (
        set x=%%B
        echo !x!
        echo !x! | findstr /r "^[^\\/?%%*:|<>\_\.-~!@#$&()+="]*$^" > nul
        echo %errorlevel%
    )
)
pause
```

I also tried it with `!errorlevel!` instead of `%errorlevel%`, which was not working.

Comment: In your sample you have to change `echo %errorlevel%`to echo !errorlevel!` as in the first case you always sees the value before any findstr was executed

Comment: @jeb, I tried using `!errorlevel!`, still it shows 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parser problems dealing with the escape characters while preparing the commands to be executed inside the pipe. The regular expression that is passed to `findstr` becomes

```
[\\/?%*:|<>\_\.-~@#$&()+=]*$
```

Try with

```dos
echo !x! | findstr /r "^^[^^\\/?%%*:|<>\_\.-~^!@#$&()+=""]*$"
```

And, as pointed by jeb, in your last code you must change `echo %errorlevel%` (variable is expanded when the `for` command is parsed) to `echo !errorlevel!` (variable is expanded before executing the `echo` command)

**edited** to adapt to comments

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "test_data=clean"                    & call :runTest
    set "test_data=with spaces"              & call :runTest
    set "test_data=with ending spaces "      & call :runTest
    set "test_data= with starting spaces"    & call :runTest
    set "test_data=with!exclamation"         & call :runTest
    set "test_data=with%%percentsign"        & call :runTest
    set "test_data=with^caret"               & call :runTest
    set "test_data=with:colon"               & call :runTest
    set "test_data=with""quotes"             & call :runTest
    set "test_data=with&ampersand"           & call :runTest
    set "test_data=with*?wildcards"          & call :runTest
    set "test_data=.\-/?%%*:|<>_~^!@#$&()+=" & call :runTest

    goto :eof

:runTest
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set test_data
        echo [!test_data!]
        (cmd /v/c"(@echo !test_data!)")| >nul findstr /x /r /c:"[^^ .\-\\/?%%*:|<>_~^!@#$&()+=""^^]*"
        echo errorlevel = !errorlevel!
    endlocal
    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output:

```
S:\>q45504784.cmd
test_data=clean
[clean]
errorlevel = 0
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=with spaces
[with spaces]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=with ending spaces
[with ending spaces ]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data= with starting spaces
[ with starting spaces]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=with!exclamation
[with!exclamation]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=with%percentsign
[with%percentsign]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=with^caret
[with^caret]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=with:colon
[with:colon]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=with""quotes
[with""quotes]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=with&ampersand
[with&ampersand]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=with*?wildcards
[with*?wildcards]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test_data=.\-/?%*:|<>_~^!@#$&()+=
[.\-/?%*:|<>_~^!@#$&()+=]
errorlevel = 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------

S:\>
```

Comment: Thanks A lot !!!!!!!!!! I was stuck with this for many hours. Just one question, I want to consider space as a special character as well.

Comment: @aniket_777, `(echo !x!| findstr /r /c:"^^[^^ \.\-\\/?%%*:|<>_~^!@#$&()+=""]*$") > nul`

Comment: Hi MC ND, its not working with `!` and `^` characters. For `!` , I added escape character as `^^!` and for `^` , I added one more cap like `^^` , still it didn't work for me.

Comment: @aniket_777, answer updated. Try the code after the edit.

Comment: MC ND but how can I make it work, when I want to check any special character in volume name as mention in the third code snippet of my question. Its removing ! and ^ character from volume label name.

Comment: @aniket_777, There are two expansion phases. During the normal expansion the value is properly retrieved, but, **if** delayed expansion is active **and** the data contains a `!`, then the delayed phase is executed and in this phase both `^` and `!` will be consumed. This can not be changed, you need to have delayed expansion disabled while expanding the `for` replaceable parameter.

Comment: Hi MC ND, it seems to be working fine using enable/disable delayedexpansion. Thanks for the suggestion :)